# How to test componentDidUpdate()?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

This is an example implementation:

```
export class Person extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onLoadProfile, onLoadPolicy, person } = this.props
    onLoadProfile(person.profile.uri)
    onLoadPolicy(person.policy.uri)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { onLoadProfile, onLoadPolicy, person } = this.props
    const prevPerson = prevProps.person.uri
    const curPerson = person.uri

    // If person has changed, update Person component
    if (prevPerson !== curPerson) {
      onLoadProfile(person.profile.uri)
      onLoadPolicy(person.policy.uri)
    }
  }
}
```

On `componentDidMount()`, I've managed to test it like this:

```
describe('<Person />', () => {
  let props
  let mountedPerson
  const mockLoadProfile = jest.fn()
  const mockLoadPolicy = jest.fn()

  const person = () => {
    if (!mountedPerson) {
      mountedPerson = mount(<Person {...props} />)
    } 
    return mountedPerson
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      onLoadProfile = mockLoadProfile,
      onLoadPolicy = mockLoadPolicy
    }
    mountedPerson = undefined
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    mockLoadProfile.mockClear()
    mockLoadPolicy.mockClear()
  })

  describe('componentDidMount', () => {
    it('loads profile', () => {
      person().instance().componentDidMount()
      expect(mockLoadProfile).toBeCalled()
    })

    it('loads policy', () => {
      person().instance().componentDidMount()
      expect(mockLoadPolicy).toBeCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

On `componentDidUpdate()`, I'd need the component to attempt to `render()` twice in order to verify if it updates when it should and vice-versa, yet I couldn't find a proper way to do it.

What is the correct approach to test a `componentDidUpdate()` method in React?

PS.: I'm using **jest**, **enzyme** and **React 15**.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I am using a different approach but you can copy the idea. You need to make a change in the props, I used the setProps() function:

```
describe('componentDidUpdate', () => {
    it('loads profile', () => { 
        const wrapper = shallow(<Person  {...props} />) as any;
        wrapper.setProps({ person: { uri: "something_different" } });
        expect(wrapper.instance().props.onLoadProfile).toBeCalled();
    })
})
```

I can see the pink in the coverage tests page is gone in the componentDidUpdate after running the test

Comment: If you also happen to have the same call in `componentDidMount`, you could do something like `expect(wrapper.instance().props.onLoadProfile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);` depending on how many props are changing how many times.

Comment: setProps has been deprecated

Comment: @albanx `setProps` deprecated long time ago in [React API](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning). However `enzyme` method is [different one](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/34#issuecomment-162344425).

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is the simplest way to test the above case but you can also consider as a solution extracting the `componentDidUpdate` logic out of the component like the following:

```js
// Component definition
export class Person extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.props.handleComponentDidUpdate(prevProps, this.currentProps)
  }
  // Rest of component
}

// Component functions/handlers testing
describe('Person component props', () => {
  describe('handleComponentDidUpdate', () => {
    it('loads profile & policy if person changes', () => {
      const onLoadPolicy = jest.fn()
      const onLoadProfile = jest.fn()
      const prevProps = {
        person: { uri: 'some-person-uri-old' },
        policy: { uri: 'some-policy-uri' },
        profile: { uri: 'some-profile-uri' },
        onLoadPolicy,
        onLoadProfile
      }
      const props = {
        person: { uri: 'some-person-uri-new' }, // person uri changes
        policy: { uri: 'some-policy-uri' },
        profile: { uri: 'some-profile-uri' },
        onLoadPolicy,
        onLoadProfile
      }

      handleComponentDidUpdate(prevProps, props)

      expect(onLoadPolicy).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(onLoadProfile).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

This way the component can be as dumb as they can and app logic can be extracted out into functions/handlers that are more easily testable. This way you can focus your testing more on the function (which is easier to test) and less on the component (which is trickier to test).

As for using the `Person` component, you simply provide the required props including `handleComponentDidUpdate`.

If you still need to test the component you can do the following simple test (Note that in this test, unlike the functions/handlers test above, we don't care about the logic of the app like person, profile, policy etc):

```js
// Component testing
describe('<Person/>', () => {
  it('should call handleComponentDidUpdate on prop change', () => {
    const handleComponentDidUpdate = jest.fn()
    const prevProps = {
      someProp: 'some-prop-prev',
      handleComponentDidUpdate
    }
    const newprops = {
      someProp: 'some-prop-new',
      handleComponentDidUpdate
    }

    const wrapper = shallow(<Person { ...prevProps } />)
    wrapper.setProps(newprops)

    expect(handleComponentDidUpdate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(prevProps, newProps)
  })
})
```